# How to associate onClick with a dynamically generated div with dojo?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am using dojo 1.9.2, and is trying to attach an onClick function on a piece of HTML code that I created on the fly, like this:

```
clickableDiv = "<div data-dojo-attach-point=\"testBtn\">Click Me!</div>";
self.racks.innerHTML = clickableDiv;
```

and then I want to give it an onClick function after, so right below the code I putted:

```
connect(this.testBtn, "onclick", alert("You Clicked It!"));
```

For some reason not only this wont work, when I refresh the page the alert "You Clicked It!" would pop up without me clicking anything...

I Have to use this dojo version, it's part of the requirement...
Any idea or suggestion on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, all solutions works great! It really helped me a lot. Now I don't know what answer to pick as the solution since they are all equally helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, dojo is part of javascript, so you can probably use some javascript function, for example:

```
clickableDiv = "<div id=\"testBtn\">Click Me!</div>";
self.racks.innerHTML = clickableDiv;
document.getElementById('testBtn').onclick=function(){alert("You Clicked It!");};
```

Comment: The way my project is set up is that the base page (HTML) has no association to the dojo files what so ever, and it's the dojo files that actively modify the base page... If I use the basic javacript code, can I still call self made functions that is not part of javascript like "alert"?

Comment: I'll Pick your solution cause I ended up using this solution in the end, but everyone else, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned in the question is correct, except for one mistake. The "onclick" event needs a handler function, not the code directly. So, enclose that alert statement by a function.

```
connect(this.testBtn, "onclick", function(){alert("You Clicked It!")});
```

Or a separate function elsewhere can be linked here a handle by passing the function or just name of the function.

```
function abcd() {
 alert('You clicked It');
}
connect(this.testBtn, "onclick", "abcd");//same as connect(this.testBtn, "onclick", abcd);
```

Answer (score 0):

When providing an event handler (or a callback in general), you have to provide the function as reference. When you use:

```js
connect(this.testBtn, "onclick", alert("You Clicked It!"));
```

You're actually saying that you want to connect the `onClick` event handler to the **return value** of that `alert()`. What you actually want is like the other answers already explained by wrapping it inside a function that is passed through by reference:

```js
connect(this.testBtn, "onclick", function() {
    alert("You Clicked It!")
});
```

However, since you're using `data-dojo-attach-point` which is generally used in widgets, you could also define your event handler in a similar way, for example:

```js
clickableDiv = "<div data-dojo-attach-point=\"testBtn\" data-dojo-attach-event=\"onClick: myClickHandler\">Click Me!</div>";
```

Then you can just write a function called `myClickHandler` in your widget that shows the alert, for example:

```js
myClickHandler: function() {
    alert("You Clicked It!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He's using dojo 1.9.2.  connect is deprecated and he should be using on:

```
on(this.testBtn, "click", function(){
    alert("You Clicked It!")
});
```

Your data-dojo-attach-point won't get picked up in dynamically placed HTML.  You would put that in a custom widget template to provide the actual reference to your node/widget.  If you did have that element in a template to begin with, you could simply use the attribute on your element:

```
data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: someFunction"
```